# keep getting "Extra content at the end of the document" error

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am currently working on an xml file for an assignment, but keep on getting a "Extra content at the end of the document" whenever I try to open the xml file in a web-browser, after having spent around an hour and a half on trying to figure out what is causing this, I still have not had any luck, so If someone could help point out the error that I have made or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it, thanks!
here is the xml content itself

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Access Data_Phase A_Test Program.css"?>
<client_information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Access Data_Client Projects_Schema.xsd"/>
<client>
        <client_ID> 1 </client_ID>
        <client_name> John Hill </client_name>
        <client_address>
                <client_address_street>
                        <client_address_street_1> 123 Broad Street </client_address_street_1>
                        <client_address_street_2> Apartment 2 </client_address_street_2>
                </client_address_street>
                <client_address_city> State College </client_address_city>
                <client_address_state> PA </client_address_state>
                <client_address_zip> 16801 </client_address_zip>
        </client_address>
        <client_phone_number> 614222333 </client_phone_number>
        <client_fax_number> 6143234444 </client_fax_number>
        <client_email> jhill@ist.psu.edu </client_email>
        <project>
                <project_number> 22 </project_number>
                <contact_person>
                        <contact_person_name> Patrick Lunney </contact_person_name>
                        <contact_person_phone_number> 5554443333 </contact_person_phone_number>
                        <contact_person_fax_number> 6667778888 </contact_person_fax_number>
                        <contact_person_email> pat@email.com </contact_person_email>
                </contact_person>
                <delivery_preference> Phone </delivery_preference>
        </project>
</client>
<client>
        <client_ID> 2 </client_ID>
        <client_name> Austin Wonderly </client_name>
        <client_address>
                <client_address_street>
                        <client_address_street_1> thompson hall </client_address_street_1>
                        <client_address_street_2> room 256 </client_address_street_2>
                </client_address_street>
                <client_address_city> University Park </client_address_city>
                <client_address_state> PA </client_address_state>
                <client_address_zip> 16802 </client_address_zip>
        </client_address>
        <client_phone_number> 7167964202 </client_phone_number>
        <client_fax_number> 7815852085 </client_fax_number>
        <client_email> ajw5293@psu.edu </client_email>
        <project>
                <project_number> 44 </project_number>
                <contact_person>
                        <contact_person_name> James Wonderly </contact_person_name>
                        <contact_person_phone_number> 7169129546 </contact_person_phone_number>
                        <contact_person_fax_number> 7166560432 </contact_person_fax_number>
                        <contact_person_email> jwonderly@aholdusa.com </contact_person_email>
                </contact_person>
                <delivery_preference> Email </delivery_preference>
        </project>
</client>
<client>
        <client_ID> 3 </client_ID>
        <client_name> Mike Jones </client_name>
        <client_address>
                <client_address_street>
                        <client_address_street_1> Park Avenue Plaza </client_address_street_1>
                        <client_address_street_2> 55 East 52nd Street </client_address_street_2>
                </client_address_street>
                <client_address_city> New York </client_address_city>
                <client_address_state> NY </client_address_state>
                <client_address_zip> 10055 </client_address_zip>
        </client_address>
        <client_phone_number> 2128105300 </client_phone_number>
        <client_fax_number> 2127543123 </client_fax_number>
        <client_email> mjones@psu.edu </client_email>
        <project>
                <project_number> 4 </project_number>
                <contact_person>
                        <contact_person_name> Tom Dombrowski </contact_person_name>
                        <contact_person_phone_number> 7815553700 </contact_person_phone_number>
                        <contact_person_fax_number> 7816326000 </contact_person_fax_number>
                        <contact_person_email> tdombrowski@msn.com </contact_person_email>
                </contact_person>
                <delivery_preference> Fax </delivery_preference>
        </project>
</client>
<client>
        <client_ID> 4 </client_ID>
        <client_name> John Neale </client_name>
        <client_address>
                <client_address_street>
                        <client_address_street_1> Four Embarcadero Center </client_address_street_1>
                        <client_address_street_2> Suite 550 </client_address_street_2>
                </client_address_street>
                <client_address_city> San Francisco </client_address_city>
                <client_address_state> CA </client_address_state>
                <client_address_zip> 94111 </client_address_zip>
        </client_address>
        <client_phone_number> 8007892742 </client_phone_number>
        <client_fax_number> 6307993834 </client_fax_number>
        <client_email> jneal@statecollege.org </client_email>
        <project>
                <project_number> 6 </project_number>
                <contact_person>
                        <contact_person_name> Tom Cyran </contact_person_name>
                        <contact_person_phone_number> 6305053700 </contact_person_phone_number>
                        <contact_person_fax_number> 6307993834 </contact_person_fax_number>
                        <contact_person_email> tcyran@slrhs.com </contact_person_email>
                </contact_person>
                <delivery_preference> Phone </delivery_preference>
        </project>
</client>
</client_information>
```

, also here is the error that I keep getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRi96.png

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual XML here (or at least enough of it to reproduce the problem). If the majority of the content is off-site, and the off-site location is unavailable, the question (and probably the answers to it) become meaningless. It's also not searchable, and not as useful to future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the error, it tells you exactly.  line 4 looks like this:

`<client_information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Access Data_Client Projects_Schema.xsd"/>`

followed by the rest of your xml.  Except that line is a closed node, so the rest of your xml is being regarded as invalid :) remove the closure at the end, like so:

`<client_information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Access Data_Client Projects_Schema.xsd">`